# how to use slotMinutes in JQuery Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When I resize the Event in fullcalendar's day view, It allow me to resize it with the difference of 30 minutes time slot. I want to reduce the period of time slot from 30 to 10 or 5. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you should just be able to specify the argument `slotMinutes` in the options when you initialize the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    slotMinutes: 5,
    // .. etc
});
```

However, as shown by **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/WpyV4/)** (click 'day' view and you should see a few events), the day view now has a scale of 5 minutes on the left.  Not sure that there's any way around this (i.e., show 30 minute intervals on the scale, but allow the events to be dragged by 5 minute intervals).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For Fullcalendar V2 use slotDuration : http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/